# Is it possible to push nitification on different date?

Tags: iphone

I am using Urban Airship and Apple to delivery push notification.
There are some users need to be notifed to do something on 1st every month
some users need to be notifed on 2nd every month
.........

Is this possible?
If sure, do I need to seperate the users before sent their device token to server?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can schedule notifications ahead of time (through the apple server), but if you have a server, then why cant u just set up a program that will read some tables or however it is you store the users notification cycle, and send the notifications when appropriate?